# Selenium Python открывает ту же страницу, после закрытия драйвера

Tags: python, selenium

Вчера начал учить selenium, столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть код, который открывает сначала https://regvk.com/id, берет оттуда id пользователя, затем открывает vk.com, проводит авторизацию и пишет сообщение этому пользователю. Без первого пункта все работало нормально, однако теперь происходит следующее: код открывает regvk, берет оттуда id, закрывает его и в многопотоке открывает заданное число потоков(в моем случае 3) снова с regvk, хотя там стоит url = vk.com и должен в многопотоке открывать этот сайт. Приложу часть кода

```py
...
...
...
url_id = 'https://regvk.com/id/'
username = 'https://vk.com/id'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
browser.get(url=url_id)
pole = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "enter")))
pole.clear()
pole.send_keys(username)
sleep(2)
browser.find_element(By.NAME, "button").click()
sleep(3)
vkid = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="result"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td')
sleep(2)
browser.close()
browser.quit()

url = "https://vk.com/"
def vk_bot(log_pass: str):
    try:
        login = log_pass[0]
        password = log_pass[1]
        agent = log_pass[2]
        options.add_argument(f"user-agent={agent}")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
        driver.get(url=url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        input_login = driver.find_element(By.ID, "index_email")
        input_login.clear()
        input_login.send_keys(login)
        ...
        ...
        ...
        if __name__ == '__main__':
        p = Pool(processes=3)
        p.map(vkbot, list(zip(log, pas, users)))
```